# A child for DynamicSupervisor – long-running jobs

Tags: erlang, elixir, background-process, erlang-supervisor

Let's say I have a simple module

```
defmodule MyWorker do
  def do_long_running_work(a, b, c) do
    # ......
  end
end
```

And DynamicSupervisor

```
defmodule MyDynamicSupervisor do
  use DynamicSupervisor

  def start_link(_arg) do
    DynamicSupervisor.start_link(__MODULE__, :ok, name: __MODULE__)
  end

  def init(:ok) do
    DynamicSupervisor.init(strategy: :one_for_one)
  end

  def add_my_worker(worker_name, game_id) do
    child_spec = {MyWorker, {worker_name, game_id}}
    DynamicSupervisor.start_child(__MODULE__, child_spec)
  end

  def remove_my_worker(worker_pid) do
    DynamicSupervisor.terminate_child(__MODULE__, worker_pid)
  end

  def children do
    DynamicSupervisor.which_children(__MODULE__)
  end

  def count_children do
    DynamicSupervisor.count_children(__MODULE__)
  end
end
```

The documentation says the `MyWorker` has to has have a `start_link` method. Moreover, the examples there suggest that `MyWorker` be `GenServer`. Altough it could also instead contain `child_spec` without having to `use GenServer`

However, `MyWorker` would be doing a **long-running** a job in `do_long_running_work()` -- the one which could last hours. Whereas `GenServer` **isn't meant to run long-running jobs** in itself, right?

How would I then go about running `MyWorker` then? What would a simple implementation of `MyWorker` look like?

What would `start_link` look like it it wasn't a `GenServer` in my case?

---

And there'd be also thousands of instances of `MyWorker` created and run via `MyDynamicSupervisor`.

I don't want to simply create tasks. I want a) manage them b) see the state of each one c) one how many there're d) have a supervisor to restart them if need be. At runtime, dynamically.

What `DynamicSupervisor` is for then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The documentation says the MyWorker has to has have a start_link
> method. Moreover, the examples there suggest that MyWorker be
> GenServer.

No.  The `child specification` tells the DynamicSupervisor how to start the child:

> The child specification is a map containing up to 6 elements. The
> first two keys in the following list are required, and the remaining
> ones are optional:
>
> :id - any term used to identify the child specification internally by
> the supervisor; defaults to the given module. This key is required.
> For supervisors, in the case of conflicting :id values, the supervisor
> will refuse to initialize and require explicit IDs. This is not the
> case for dynamic supervisors though.
>
> :start - a tuple with the module-function-args to be invoked to start
> the child process. This key is required.

https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/1.14.4/Supervisor.html#module-child-specification

For instance:

```
  def add_my_worker(worker_module_name, 
                    worker_function_name, 
                    list_of_worker_function_args, 
                    game_id) do
    child_spec = %{
          id: game_id,
          start: {worker_module_name, worker_function_name, list_of_worker_function_args}
    }
    DynamicSupervisor.start_child(__MODULE__, child_spec)
  end
```

You could call `add_my_worker()` like this:

```
add_my_worker(MyWorker, 
              :do_long_running_work, 
              [10, :abc, "hello"],
              23561)
```

The DynamicSupervisor would then call:

```
spawn_link(MyWorker, :do_long_running_work, [10, :abc, "hello"])
```

Comment: I've asked about `DynamicSupervisor`, but you've shown me a link to and the specs of `Supervisor`. Why?

Comment: And where did `spawn_link` come from? And why?

Comment: The link given is to **child spec**, not to a supervisor. `DynamicSupervisor` is a `Supervisor` [under the hood](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/v1.14.4/lib/elixir/lib/dynamic_supervisor.ex#L258-L266). _Sidenote:_ what you call `MyWorker` is by no mean a worker, it’s even not a process.

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin alright. But `MyWorker` could be called whatever one wish to call it. Essentually, it's simply a module. I refer to it as worker.

Comment: You stated “thousands of instances of `MyWorker`” which is nonsense, one cannot have instances of a module. One might want to start and supervise a process, so we have `Task` and `Task.Supervisor`. If you insist on using `DynamicSupervisor`, and do not use `Task`, you’d need to start a process running your function, e. g. with [`spawn_link/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.html#spawn_link/3), and you may pass this function as a runner in the `child_spec`.

Comment: @Koklushkin, *I've asked about DynamicSupervisor, but you've shown me a link to and the specs of Supervisor. Why?* --  Because the docs say that the second argument of `DynamicSupervisor.start_child/2` has the type `Supervisor.child_spec()`

Comment: *And where did spawn_link come from?* -- In Elixir you can start a process with several functions, two of which are `spawn/1` and `spawn_link/3`.  A DynamicSupervisor has to start the child/worker process somehow.  The information in the child spec provides the necessary info for the DynamicSupervisor to start the process.  The way any Supervisor knows a process has died is by linking to the process.  Normally, that would cause the linked process to die as well, but you don't want your Supervisor to die when a child dies, so the Supervisor process does something called "trapping exits".

Comment: ....When a process is "trapping exits", and any linked process dies, Elixir sends a message to the still alive process, rather than killing the still alive process, which can be read from the still alive process's mailbox. That provides the mechanism for a Supervisor/Dynamic Supervisor to know when the children it started have died.  `spawn_link/3` both starts a process and links to it--the function should be pronounced "spawn and link".

Answer (score 1):

The long-running job is best backed by a [supervised] [`Task`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Task.html).

Furthermore, one does not need `DynamicSupervisor` for that, [`Task.Supervisor`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Task.Supervisor.html) would suffice.

Comment: `DynamicSupervisor` is needed because I'll be running the tasks at runtime, dynamically, which I haven't mentioned because my question isn't about this. It's about how I'd to **use** `DynamicSupervisor` in the case described.

Comment: You can dynamically call `Task.Supervisor.async_nolink/5` and other functions to create Tasks at runtime.  (It'd help if this answer included examples and not just documentation links.)

Comment: @DavidMaze the documentation linked is full of examples, it makes zero sense to copy-paste them here.

Comment: @DavidMaze I don't want to simply "create" tasks. I want a) manage them b) see the state of each one c) one how many there're d) have a supervisor to restart them if need be. What's `DynamicSupervisor` is for then?